# Broken_Barh doesn't follow the order of the dataframe used

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart

I am trying to create a broken barplot showing the growth of different crop types. The first part needs to present the planting month followed by the growing period and the harvesting period. Unfortunately, I am not able to provide the right order of the bars. I want to create a diagonal line of the harvesting periods so it shows that the whole year through harvesting can take place. Due to the strange order, my code provides I am also not able to connect the right labels to my y-axis.

[image]

It seems that the code functions at the start correctly and then suddenly something goes wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_excel("twee.xlsx")

df[['Plant1','Plant2']] = df.Plant.str.split(',',expand=True)
df[['Grow1','Grow2']] = df.Grow.str.split(',',expand=True)
df[['Harv1','Harv2']] = df.Harv.str.split(',',expand=True)

columnlist = ['Plant1','Plant2','Grow1','Grow2','Harv1','Harv2']

for i in columnlist:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(by=['Harv1'],ascending=True)

y = []
for i in range(10,((1+len(df.Species))*10),10):
    y.append((i,9))

months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
xaxis = []
for i in range(len(months)):
    xaxis.append(i)

species = df.Species.tolist()

yaxis = []
a = 15
for i in range(len(species)):
    b = a + i*10
    yaxis.append(b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = ([row.Plant1,row.Plant2], [row.Grow1,row.Grow2], [row.Harv1,row.Harv2])
    temp2 = [1,2,3]
    a=0
    for j in temp:
        temp2[a] =  ( int(j[0]), int(j[1]) )
        a += 1 
    ax.broken_barh(temp2, y[index],
               facecolors=('#F4A460', '#32CD32', '#FF7F50'), label=species[index])

ax.set_ylim(5, max(yaxis)+20)
ax.set_xlim(0, max(xaxis))
ax.set_xlabel('Months')
ax.set_xticks(xaxis, labels=months)
ax.set_yticks(yaxis, labels=species)
ax.grid(False)
plt.title("Seasonal Planting East Capitol Urban Farm")
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.annotate('race interrupted', (61, 25),
            xytext=(0.8, 0.9), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            fontsize=16,
            horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')
plt.show()
```

I would really appreciate your help!

EDIT:
This is the data I used.

[image]

Comment: Can you pls share the data used for the same, so that the error can be replicated. At least a sample of data which shows the order issue please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sorting the dataframe, the indexes are not reset. So, as you are iterating through the rows, the rows are getting messed up. You need to change the sort to - `df = df.sort_values(by=['Harv1'],ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)`. This will reset the index to the new sorted list.

The updated code and graph as here. For future reference, please paste the table in a way one can copy the data into a text or excel file

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.read_excel("twee.xlsx")

df[['Plant1','Plant2']] = df.Plant.str.split(',',expand=True)
df[['Grow1','Grow2']] = df.Grow.str.split(',',expand=True)
df[['Harv1','Harv2']] = df.Harv.str.split(',',expand=True)

columnlist = ['Plant1','Plant2','Grow1','Grow2','Harv1','Harv2']

for i in columnlist:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(int)

df = df.sort_values(by=['Harv1'],ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)

y = []
for i in range(10,((1+len(df.Species))*10),10):
    y.append((i,9))

months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
xaxis = []
for i in range(len(months)):
    xaxis.append(i)

species = df.Species.tolist()

yaxis = []
a = 15
for i in range(len(species)):
    b = a + i*10
    yaxis.append(b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = ([row.Plant1,row.Plant2], [row.Grow1,row.Grow2], [row.Harv1,row.Harv2])
    temp2 = [1,2,3]
    a=0
    for j in temp:
        temp2[a] =  ( int(j[0]), int(j[1]) )
        a += 1 
    ax.broken_barh(temp2, y[index],
               facecolors=('#F4A460', '#32CD32', '#FF7F50'), label=species[index])

ax.set_ylim(5, max(yaxis)+20)
ax.set_xlim(0, max(xaxis))
ax.set_xlabel('Months')
ax.set_xticks(xaxis)
ax.set_xticklabels(months)
ax.set_yticks(yaxis)
ax.set_yticklabels(species)
ax.grid(False)
plt.title("Seasonal Planting East Capitol Urban Farm")
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.annotate('race interrupted', (61, 25),
            xytext=(0.8, 0.9), textcoords='axes fraction',
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            fontsize=16,
            horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='top')
fig.set_size_inches(12,25)
plt.show()
```

[image]